# When mocking core modules in Jest, don't mock it in dependencies

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocking, jestjs

When I mock a core module in Jest, like `jest.mock('fs')`, and I create a file called `__mocks__/fs.js`, then I am using a mocked version of the module.

However, if any of the dependencies in the modules I'm testing also use `fs`, then they use the mocked version, which breaks them.

Is there a way to unmock these core modules, when they are used by deps, but otherwise not in my own modules?

Or is there an alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: The [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) actually suggests to avoid performing disk operations while executing the tests to increase the performance. You can check the [examples](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#examples) where the *fs* module is manually mocked.

Comment: Okay thanks. But other than the `fs` module than, like say the `path` module, is there a way to achieve this? Because some NPM packages require core modules like `fs` and `path` in one way or another.

Comment: Hm, not sure if such extraction is possible. The docs suggest using `genMockFromModule` where you basically automatically mock your node module and then add your custom overrides to it. So in your case, you'd also mock the `path` module. But maybe you'll find a workaround and it would be great if you'd post it here.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will continue researching.